# How to track number of occurrences with set.union()

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, set

So, I'm looping through a bunch of docs creating a list of all unique words and sequential groups of words in the documents (obviously, the strings I'm looking at are pretty short).

```
globallist=[]
for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.html')):
     mystr = "some text I want"
     stuff = re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  mystr).split()
     wordlist = [''.join(stuff[i:j]) for i in range(len(stuff)) for j in range(i+1, len(stuff)+1)]
     globallist = set.union(set(globallist), set(wordlist))
```

I want to track occurrences with globallist as I go so that at the end I'll already have a count of ***how many documents*** contain each string in the list. I plan to delete any element that only occurs in one document. What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script below should help to give you some ideas.

You are attempting to parse HTML files, so ideally you need to extract only the text from each file without any of the HTML markup. This can be done using a library such as `BeautifulSoup`. Next it is best to lowercase all of the words to ensure you catch words using different case. Python's `collections.Counter` can be used to count all of the words, and from that a list containing only words with a count of one can be constructed. Finally a count of your phrases can be made.

All of this information can then be stored on a per file basis into `file_stats`. The results are then displayed at the end.

From that, you will be able to see how many of the documents contain the text you were looking for.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import collections
import glob
import re   
import os

path = r'mypath'
file_stats = []

search_list = ['some text I want', 'some other text']
search_list = [phrase.lower() for phrase in search_list]    # Ensure list is all lowercase

for filename in glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.html')):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_input:
        html = f_input.read()

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

    # Remove style and script sections from the HTML
    for script in soup(["style", "script"]):
        script.extract() 

    # Extract all text
    text = soup.get_text().encode('utf-8')

    # Create a word list in lowercase
    word_list = [word.lower() for word in re.sub("[^\w]", " ",  text).split()]

    # Search for matching phrases
    phrase_counts = dict()
    text = ' '.join(word_list)

    for search in search_list:
        phrase_counts[search] = text.count(search)

    # Calculate the word counts
    word_counts = collections.Counter(word_list)

    # Filter unique words
    unique_words = sorted(word for word, count in word_counts.items() if count == 1)

    # Create a list of unique words and phrase matches for each file
    file_stats.append([filename, unique_words, phrase_counts])

# Display the results for all files
for filename, unique_words, phrase_counts in file_stats:
    print '{:30} {}'.format(filename, unique_words)
    for phrase, count in phrase_counts.items():
        print '  {} : {}'.format(phrase, count)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a `set` of words for each document, and update a [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) with the per file words. The `set` per file avoiding counting words more than once per file, the `Counter` seamlessly sums across files. For a super simple example counting individual words (without tracking which file they came from):

```
from collections import Counter

totals = Counter()
for file in allfiles:
    with open(file) as f:
        totals.update(set(f.read().split()))
```